# Pentaho report generating log (not report designer)

Tags: pentaho

I have been searching here for a while, than i decided to write a question, since I am not able to find anything helpful.

I just get assigned to pentaho in my company, so I still consider myself as novice when its about Pentaho.

So, here is my question: 
I was doing some changes in one report already working. It has to show some data from DB and also pictures. And that was the problem, report was not showing pictures. But it was showing data and after click for picture, error.

So i added symlink from tomcat/webapps/ to /var/dav/davserver where those screens are (as adviced man who was working on it before me).
But it did that, whole report freezed after pushing "view report" since davserver directory has some hundretthousand pictures.

In order to not kill server, we decided to remove it from there, since we need to redesign whole screens saving.

But, when I delete that column from my report, it freezes anyway.

and my question is: Is there any web report log, where I can see all errors and operations that pentaho run when generating report? I want to see, why is it freezing after pushing "View report".

Many thanks, RastoR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two log files generated in Pentaho depending on your log4j properties.

One file can be viewed from the following location also told earlier:

**\biserver-ce\tomcat\logs\catalina.out**

And the second file can be accessed from the following path in your bi-server:

**\biserver-ce\tomcat\bin\pentaho.log**

Make sure that for adding pictures in your report, the Static Image Box is used and the path to the picture file is defined correctly in the path. These pictures have to be present inside the bi-server similarly how you place your .xml and .xaction files. One good way of doing that is making a separate folder inside this directory for all your pictures and picking it from there:

**\biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions**

Answer (score 1):

As you're talking about server side things here all you need to know is that Pentaho is nothing more than a standard tomcat webapp. So go to the tomcat logs directory and look at catalina.out

does it work when you run the report in the report designer tool?  Does sound odd to be "freezing" like that, may be worth checking what network requests it is doing and seeing if they resolve ok etc.

Comment: I have been looking into log, and I dont see any error related to given report.

I have been also trying select, and it takes over 10 sec to select data from one hour interval. Indexes over table columns are created.

Tis same setup (report, db, select) is also on other server, where it works fine. When I compare selects from same 1 hour interval 05:00-06:00, select on the "broken server" took about 10 seconds. Select on working one, took about 0,2 sec. I think its too big diference even though I take from the account of the differences.

is there any way how to check what slows down database?

Comment: for such big differences there must be something different, if the DB is setup the same then check versions java/jdbc etc.  Maybe the db is running in a different configuration?  If it is definately the query being slow at least that rules out pentaho reporting.