# generating PDF reports stopped to work

Tags: pdf, pentaho

my company is using Pentaho 3.8.0 already few years (two or so).

Until this week, we had no problem with generating reports in PDF format. Unfortunately, this week we had some memory issues on our server, where pentaho is running and I had quite busy times with it, where admin killed pentaho to solve memory issues.

I do not know what he exactly did, but I had to restart whole biserver several times to make it work. But it wasn't sending scheduled reports, so i Refreshed everything in Administration console, which made Scheduled report to be sent again.

But, when I try to generate PDF file, or when PDF report is send via schedule, file is not readable.
On web, it says "file not found'. As schedule, it send PDF file, but only 1kb and it says "File is corrupted"..

How to check PDF generating engine, or restart it, or something  similar? (Restarting server is of course not possible).

Comment: I'm sorry, but the PDF generating engine used by Pentaho is obsolete and Pentaho has no intentions to switch to a more recent version, see http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?128357-iText-Licensing for more info. As long as we (the people from iText Software) don't have a business relationship with Pentaho, we can't check what's wrong with Pentaho's use of the obsolete version of our PDF engine, see http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq (Note that we don't agree with the allegation that our licensing terms are draconian.)

Comment: Sorry but i am not sure where is your point. Does that mean that I have no option to analyze my Pentaho's PDF geenrating engine?

Comment: Pentaho uses an obsolete and unsupported version of iText (dating from 2009) as PDF generating engine. iText is a product distributed by the iText Group, but Pentaho declares on its forum that Pentaho doesn't want to upgrade to a more recent version of iText, nor to establish a business relationship with the iText Group. As a Pentaho user, you should be aware that nobody at iText is responsible if a problem arises due to Pentaho's use of our product. You are, of course, free to analyze the problem on your own, or, if you're a Pentaho customer, to contact Pentaho directly with your problem.

Comment: Forget Bruno's FUD. The problem you have is not with iText - this library runs stable and Pentaho fully supports its customers on it. We have no had any problems with iText. bruno, please dont act so desperate ;)

However, it seems that your scheduler is crocked. To test whether all of the reporting is broken or just the scheduling, try to run the report interactively first. If that works, your reports are fine and the scheduler is to blame. At that point, check that you have enough space for your pentaho-solutions directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the logs first. They contain an overview of the error being thrown. Check out this post on details for viewing logs '[Pentaho report generating log (not report designer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023512/pentaho-report-generating-log-not-report-designer/21675626#21675626)'.

If that does not help then try to generate your report in any other format like .xls from your server. In case your server is hardcoded to throw reports only in .pdf format, then you can publish your .xmls and .xactions directly in your Pentaho bi-server and generate the report in the .xls format. The excel file can be opened even if it has errors and the error code can be obtained from there.

Now from my knowledge, the error codes indicate two scenarios mostly:

1. There is a problem in your .xaction file which can be due to the connection arguments being passed or the data not querying properly.
2. If all this is correct, then the error code will indicate something like a connection issue. In this case the only option you have is to restart the server and check. Sometimes deleting the files from the server and placing them again and the refreshing it also helps.

Try some of these options. Hope you figure out your issue. Good Luck.

Comment: The problem was, that I have had some wrong data in config file, it was wrong ISO code for language. I found it in lgos, and after fixing its working now :)

So right answer was "check logs", thanks